# Why is Terser minimizer not dropping spaces & newlines when running in watch mode?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5

#### Situation

I have a working webpack configuration that includes the EslintWebpackPlugin (`fix: false`) as part of the preprocessing plugins and when there were no lint errors, webpack correctly output the expected minimized build.

But, when I had numerous lint errors and my workflow required a rerun of the build each time I desired to re-evaluate the build. I tried to increase my workflow speed by using the `--watch` option on webpack to give me instant feedback on each manual lint fix.  This partially worked but my integration with prettier through `eslint-plugin-prettier` would not be considered during the next iteration of the `webpack --watch`.  To fix this, I modified the ESLintPlugin config in `webpack.config.js` to set the `fix: true` based on the WEBPACK_WATCH environment variable. *I don't desire the regular build command to also apply lint fixes automatically since it doesn't lead to the code being fixed.*

#### Problem

On the surface this solution works as I get instant feedback on each lint fix as it is modified and webpack stays in sync with prettier/prettier errors as they resolve.  **BUT upon review of the output bundle, now the bundle has a bunch of spaces and newlines in it instead of minimizing them as it should have.**

Problems identified:

1. ESLintPlugin while in watch mode seems to cache errors even after a save, Requires `fix: true` for watch mode updates.
2. Webpack Watch mode causes errors in the TerserPlugin which prevent a proper minimized bundle.

#### Additional Troubleshooting Findings:

- I found that simply running webpack in watch mode and removing eslintplugin configuration, the output bundle does not minify properly. If the same configuration is run without `--watch`, the bundle is perfect. (Problem 2 isolation)

#### Files

```js
// webpack.config.js

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const path = require("path");
const SheBangPlugin = require("webpack-shebang-plugin");
const ESLintPlugin = require("eslint-webpack-plugin");
const thisModule = require("./package.json");

function buildConfig(env) {
  return {
    entry: "./parse.js",
    target: "node",
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
      filename: path.basename(thisModule.main)
    },
    plugins: [
      new SheBangPlugin({
        chmod: 0o755
      }),
      new ESLintPlugin({
        fix: env.WEBPACK_WATCH
      })
    ],
    optimization: {
      minimize: true,
      usedExports: true
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".js", ".json"]
    }
  };
}

module.exports = (env) => {
  const config = buildConfig(env);
  if (isProduction) {
    config.mode = "production";
  } else {
    config.mode = "development";
  }
  return config;
};
```

Snapshot of bundle.js in a vscode with word-wrap on.

[image: snapshot of bundle.js]

Is there a problem with my configuration or are these bugs?  What is it that changes when webpack goes into watch mode which causes a conflict with the TerserPlugin?

Comment: This isn't what you asked, but why are you running *source* checking tools during your *build* process?  IMHO both eslint and prettier do not belong in your build pipeline and should be a) integrated with your IDE, b) run manually, and/or c) tied to a version-control hook.

Comment: @Coderer, although your opinion is valid, I don't believe that the community is in full agreement with you.  Facebook/Create-React-App, and @vue/cli both configure their devserver with the ESLintPlugin enabled, ie. run lint before build as part of the pipeline. I'm in agreement with these tools because of the instant feedback. I do agree with you that at a minimum C should exist regardless, and to help out the developer in real-time A should be configured. B is too risky to be left by itself because humans are forgetful &/or lazy

Comment: @Coderer, something that is not mentioned above is that this is for a project that is going to be published in the npm registry on npmjs.com and `npm publish` command is not necessarily connected to source control but it does upload build artifacts.  Linters detect undesirable implementations so adding it to the build process helps ensure the published artifacts are to standard before fully public.

Comment: I agree that relying on (b) is a bad idea, but you've got the other two automated hooks to prop up forgetful humans like me.  Also, my `prepublish` package.json script includes `npm run lint` (and `npm run test`).  If it fails, `publish` stops cold.  There are plenty of hook points available to make sure the linter keeps your code clean without also plumbing it into the build process.  My point was that every tool you use should do one thing well -- webpack builds a bundle from source, and you don't need a linter for that.